Permission error when mounting ext4 drive linux
I'm trying to mount an internal hdd of mine in Manjaro.
This is the result of lsblk, I want to mount sda2
[hamjaro mnt]# lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda      8:0    0   3.6T  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0    16M  0 part 
└─sda2   8:2    0   3.6T  0 part 
sdb      8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   300M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sdb2   8:18   0 931.2G  0 part /

to this path, /mnt/4tb
[hamjaro mnt]# ls -l
total 8
d--------- 2 root root 4096 Aug 15 23:38 4tb
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 14 21:51 nas

So I run this command as root
mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/4tb

This command runs without error. Checking the ownership of the 4tb folder i can see
[hamjaro mnt]# ls -l
total 8
drw-rw-rw- 3 ham  ham  4096 Aug 19 18:52 4tb
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 14 21:51 nas
[hamjaro mnt]# ls -l 4tb
total 16
drwx------ 2 ham ham 16384 Aug 15 23:23 lost+found
-rw-r--r-- 1 ham ham     0 Aug 15 23:44 test.txt

my main account ham is both the owner and the group owner of the root folder, and the test file inside "test.txt".
but when i try to access this folder from the ham account i get the following issue
[ham@hamjaro mnt]$ ls -l
total 8
drw-rw-rw- 3 ham  ham  4096 Aug 19 18:52 4tb
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 14 21:51 nas
[ham@hamjaro mnt]$ ls -l 4tb
ls: cannot access '4tb/lost+found': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '4tb/test.txt': Permission denied
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? lost+found
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? test.txt
[ham@hamjaro mnt]$ cd 4tb
bash: cd: 4tb: Permission denied
[ham@hamjaro mnt]$ touch 4tb/test1.txt
touch: cannot touch '4tb/test1.txt': Permission denied

I get the same results whether i try to mount from the mount command or fstab.
sda2 is a freshly formatted ext4 drive, the only data on it is test.txt which i manually created myself.
I don't understand what I am doing wrong. This is my fstab incase its relevant. There are no related errors in my dmesg
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a device; this may
# be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices that works even if
# disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system>                           <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
UUID=E4AE-B476                            /boot/efi      vfat    umask=0077 0 2
UUID=43330615-f786-470d-b568-84d8f9a05696 /              ext4    defaults,noatime 0 1
tmpfs                                     /tmp           tmpfs   defaults,noatime,mode=1777 0 0
/dev/sda2                                 /mnt/4tb       ext4    defaults,noatime,rw 0 2
# UUID=192d538d-accd-4f5a-b14c-e6b5d4663853 /mnt/4tb       ext4    defaults,noatime,rw 0 2

I'm using Manjaro 24.0.6 on kernel 6.9.12

Add x permission for ham on 4tb

thank you very much that works. if you post that as an answer i will accept it as correct.
